# Flex Column Chart customization

Tags: apache-flex, charts, legend

When I customized the ColumnChart in Flex by overrided updateDisplayList function, colors in legend no longer display. As you will see in the below picture:

http://i41.tinypic.com/mim35d.png

Does I missed anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to look into the source code, here is what I did.

override protected function 
    updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

```
        var fill:IFill;
        var state:String = "";

        if (_data is ChartItem && _data.hasOwnProperty('fill'))
        {
            state = _data.currentState;
            fill = _data.fill;
        }       
        else
            fill = GraphicsUtilities.fillFromStyle(getStyle('fill'));

        var color:uint;
        var adjustedRadius:Number = 0;

        color = ColorUtil.adjustBrightness2(GraphicsUtilities.colorFromFill(fill),-20);
        fill = new SolidColor(color);       
        adjustedRadius = getStyle('adjustedRadius');
        if (!adjustedRadius)
            adjustedRadius = 0;


        var stroke:IStroke = getStyle("stroke");

        var w:Number = stroke ? stroke.weight / 2 : 0;

        var rc:Rectangle = new Rectangle(w - adjustedRadius, w - adjustedRadius, width - 2 * w + adjustedRadius * 2, height - 2 * w + adjustedRadius * 2);

        var g:Graphics = graphics;
        g.clear();      
        g.moveTo(rc.left,rc.top);
        if (stroke)
            stroke.apply(g);
        if (fill)
            fill.begin(g,rc);
        g.lineTo(rc.right-5,rc.top);
        g.lineTo(rc.right-5,rc.bottom);
        g.lineTo(rc.left+5,rc.bottom);
        g.lineTo(rc.left+5,rc.top);
        if (fill)
            fill.end(g);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the legend markers by using legendMarkerRenderer. This article shows you how towards the bottom:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_formatting_13.html

You can also customize your LegendItem's even more by creating your own LegendItem's:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/LegendItem.html

Example to customize your Legend:
[How to exclude series in legend (Flex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491303/how-to-exclude-series-in-legend-flex/2495314#2495314)