# Hide items from legend in flex chart

Tags: apache-flex

I have a LineChart continaing 6 lineseries. I should be able to pass parametrers to server using HTTPservice. But then the returned XML may contain information for a single line series or for all the lineseries. The problem, if we have a value for a single lineseries , the legend should contain also only one item and similarly for multiple items.

The legend also contains equal options. But if the xml returns value only for bugs , we should have

the legend should have only one item. 
Help me out!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question well, but this answer will help you understand how to better control your LineChart's legend:
[How to exclude series in legend (Flex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491303/how-to-exclude-series-in-legend-flex/2495314#2495314)

Let me know if this helps, or please clarify your question.